# Compare two rows but keep with same unique keys and keep only that bigger quantity with Pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe in pyspark

[image: dataframe]

I need to keep only the rows if quantity if bigger than other row and have same id and price.

expected result

[image: result]

I tried that but it just overiding the row withut comparing the rows like current quantity is null and previous is 3 it keeps null instead of 3

```
 grp_by = ['id', 'price']
 df_fin = df.groupBy(*grp_by).agg(
            *[first(c).alias(c) for c in list(set(df.columns) - set(grp_by))]
        )
```

Comment: Use `max` instead of `first` to get biggest number.